# Converting oven time and temp from convection to conventional

Tags: oven

I watched a British recipe that instructed for it to be baked at 180 fan. I live in the states and use a conventional oven. What do I set it at. Also, would the baking time change?

Comment: This question (on an international forum) is about converting from/to oven types in different countries - that means it would be really helpful if you describe what a *conventional oven* is ;-)

Comment: @JanDoggen I might be wrong, but that is one of the very few things which I thought to be fairly consistent? An conventional oven has a top and bottom heating element and transfers heat slower than a fan oven that moves the hot air around?

Comment: @Stephie It is not. Gas ovens e.g.

Comment: @Stephie most ovens in the US don't use upper elements except when broiling.

Comment: yeah i though side elements were the standard

Answer (score 5):

180 fan is equal to 200 <sup>o</sup>C= (400 <sup>o</sup>F).

I attached a chart I didn't create I use for reference.

> [image: screenshot]

Answer (score 4):

180 fan is 180 degrees Centigrade with the fan on. The general advice when converting from a fan to a non fan oven is increase temperature 15-20 degrees, so the range you are looking for is between 383 and 392 degrees Fahrenheit. If you have a digital stove I'd say set it for 390, if it's a dial you'll need to eyeball it.